# An upper bound on the minimum number of vertices in a girth 5 graph of chromatic number $k$

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Is there a known upper bound on the minimum number of vertices in a graph with girth 5 and chromatic number $k$? Could you also give references for this?

Comment: I believe there's a construction based on random Cayley graphs of $PGL_2(n)$: assign $n^\frac52$ colors uniformly random to the elements of $PGL_2(n)$,  such that $a$ and $a^{-1}$ have same colors. By [counting monochromatic cycles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333536/probability-of-words-summing-to-1-in-s-n-or-pgl-2n), there's a girth-5 graph induced by some color with high probablity. Now one should compute the spectral gap and use the Hoffman chromatic bound to conclude that $χ$ grows like $Ω(n^α)$, thus establishing a polynomial bound.